# can I pass variables through URL while using htaccess RewriteRule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if it is possible to pass another variable through URL while already passing a variable using .htacces?

for example,

```
RewriteRule ^browse/([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ browse/index.php?brand=$1
```

lets say, `website.com/browse/index.php?brand=louis-vuitton`
was rewritten into `website.com/browse/louis-vuitton`

is it possible for me to use another variable like this:

```
website.com/browse/louis-vuitton/?sort=name
```

Comment: where would this variable come from? another part of the incoming url?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is, you simply add [QSA] After the rewrite condition

```
RewriteRule ^browse/([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ browse/index.php?brand=$1 [QSA]
```

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

Comment: you deserve a +10! too bad Vote Up requires 15 reputation